# krunner doesn't find some files

Tags: search, krunner

I have installed kubuntu 19.10 and krunner doesn't find many files, however baloosearch find these files as expected. And of course I have enabled the desktop search in the settings of plasma search.

By example: I have a folder plenty of PDFs and MDs (markdown) files located in a mounted disk (this disk is mounted automatically at the start). Then making a search in the console using the `baloosearch` command I can find any file there (I put some words or string of the name of a file and then the location and complete name of the file appear almost instantly) however writting the same words or the complete name of a file in krunner then for some files (specially the new ones) they doesn't appear except in the case that I used it recently.

My plasmashell version is 5.16.5. I added the section of plugins in the configuration file, as has been asked in a comment:

```
[Plugins]
CharacterRunnerEnabled=false
DictionaryEnabled=false
Kill RunnerEnabled=true
PIM Contacts Search RunnerEnabled=false
PowerDevilEnabled=false
Spell CheckerEnabled=false
baloosearchEnabled=true
bookmarksEnabled=false
browsertabsEnabled=false
calculatorEnabled=true
desktopsessionsEnabled=false
katesessionsEnabled=false
konsoleprofilesEnabled=false
krunner_appstreamEnabled=false
kwinEnabled=false
locationsEnabled=true
org.kde.activitiesEnabled=true
org.kde.datetimeEnabled=false
org.kde.windowedwidgetsEnabled=false
placesEnabled=true
plasma-desktopEnabled=false
recentdocumentsEnabled=true
servicesEnabled=true
shellEnabled=true
unitconverterEnabled=true
webshortcutsEnabled=true
windowsEnabled=false
```

However nothing unusual or strange is here. I tried enabling everything and restarting but nothing changes.

The output of `ls -l ~/.config/krunnerrc` is

```
-rw------- 1 user user 7236 abr 16 04:08 /home/user/.config/krunnerrc
```

Someone knows how to fix this behavior?

Comment: Asked here: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/g27ab8/some_files_found_with_baloosearch_but_not_with/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x Please monitor that as well. • Also, please [edit] your question to provide the output of `plasmashell --version`. The version in Kubuntu 19.10 depends on whether you have the kubuntu-backports ppa enabled. • You could also provide information about the location of the files `krunner` doesn't find but `baloosearch` does.

Comment: @DKBose thank you for your help, I added more information. Indeed I send a ticket about this in the KDE bugs reporting web. This bug was already reported two years ago (with no solution) by an user of a manjaro distribution. You can see the ticket [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420129). Also this was reported [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1525365/krunner-file-search-out-of-date-despite-baloosearch-giving-correct-results#comment2342981_1525365)

Comment: @DKBose the search in dolphin works fine (I did it from the root folder). Maybe there is something wrong in the definition of the plugin that makes the search for krunner?

Comment: Okay, I guess Dolphin is using "pure" baloo whereas krunner is messed up in some way. Pity!

Comment: @DKBose it seems that dolphin doesn't use internally the command `baloosearch` because the search take some time (minutes), however in console with `baloosearch` the search for ANY file take approximately a quarter of a second!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the index file of baloo (with baloo disabled) and after re-enabling baloo solved the issue. I suspected of baloo because it still find some old files (already deleted some months ago).

What was really weird is that baloo was capable of find some files that krunner dont find. Really really weird.

Comment: please add details on how to disable and how to remove the index file (where is that?)