# How to search for files with Krunner?

Tags: kubuntu, search, symbolic-link, plasma-5, krunner

I was expecting krunner (and maybe the other Launchers like  Application Launcher, Application Menu, Application Dashboard) to find files the way [Synapse does](https://askubuntu.com/a/1180227/925128) or [even Whisker menu](https://askubuntu.com/a/785894/925128). For some time these Plasma tools have searched and found [only files and folders in $HOME](https://askubuntu.com/q/1325401/925128), and even there they still find [no links](https://askubuntu.com/q/1325396/925128). (The only thing that krunner does more than the rest is to show "Places".)

- **How is Krunner supposed to find files?**
- **Is it supposed to search for files and folders outside $HOME?**
- **Should I type something like "search" or "locate" before typing
  the name of the searched item?**
- On a separate drive some files and folders are seen, but not all of them. What is the difference between the ones that are searchable and the rest? **Could it be the depth of directory levels?**

I see posts saying that it should find files, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227401/925128), albeit complaining that it does not as expected.

But, before complaining that it does not, I would like to know what is the way in which the search should be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Krunner#Open_files.2C_folders_and_devices) says:

> If you don't know the path to a file, simply type the name of the file. If the file is a recently opened document, KRunner will list it for you. If you have enabled "File Search" provided by Baloo daemon, you can also search your computer for the file by its indexed contents. KRunner will also open folders you've bookmarked in Dolphin (in your Places sidebar) if you type their name in. What's more, if you want to access devices on your system (both mounted and unmounted), you can do that, too. KRunner will even provide device-specific options.

Comment: The fact is that excepting $HOME (and I don't know for sure as I don't have a lot of files and multi-level folders there) files are only partially indexed and found. It might be related to the date of their creation.